disjoint event implies not independent
I've read that two events $A,B$ are independent if and only if $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$. Now, I also know if two events are disjoint then they are not independent. Meaning if $P(A\cap B)=0$ then $A,B$ are not independent. (Assuming that P(A),P(B)>0).
Now, I also read that coin flips are independent. But if we have one flip, then $P(H\cap T)=0$ because it is not possible to flip H and T at the same time. But $P(H),P(T)>0$. So is this flip not independent? Where is my mistake Im so confused. Thanks!

The events of getting heads and tails in a single toss are not independent.

What is independent about coinflips are the results from different coins.
If A="Result coint 1" and B="Result coin 2", then A and B are independent.
But in your example A and B are both related to the result of the same coin. That is not independent.

When you say, "coin flips are independent", what exactly do you mean? Afaik it means the following- if we flip a coin more than once , every flip will be independent of every other flip.
This means that for the events $A_n$ :=getting H for the nth flip and $B_m$:=getting T for the mth flip, you will have $A_n$ independent of $B_m$ for any choice of m and n with m not equal to n. Disjoint or Mutually Exclusive events (i.e. H or T for the same flip) will not be independent.
